# Явное приведение типов данных в C

Tags: c

Почему код ниже работает?

```
int main(void) {
    printf("%d", (int)(249.5/0.05));
    return 0;
}
```

А следующий код нет?

```
int main(void) {
    printf("%d", (int)(249.5)/(int)(0.05));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что на ноль делить нельзя!

`(int)(0.05)` = 0